# I add plugin to my django cms when I to publish and view the page, It's alway report the error Project matching query does not exist

Tags: python, css, django

I add plugin to my django cms when I to publish and view the page, It's alway report the error Project matching query does not exist.All my plugin page report this error.Where is the error take palce?

```
DoesNotExist at /jdk/testcenter/testcase/
Project matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.239.173.54/jdk/testcenter/testcase/?preview=1
Django Version: 1.5.8
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Project matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 404
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/wuwenzhong/itms',
 '/home/wuwenzhong/itms/itrac_2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Wed, 28 Sep 2016 08:57:01 +0800
Error during template rendering
In template /home/wuwenzhong/itms/templates/requirement.html, error at line 9
Project matching query does not exist.
1   {% extends "frame.html" %}
2   
3   {% block base_content %}
4       <div class="case_class">
5           <div class="ui_head_area">
6               <span class="head_title">TestCase Management</span>
7               <hr>
8           </div>
9           {% placeholder req_placeholder_01 %}
10          {% placeholder req_placeholder_02 %}
11      </div>
12  
13      <div class="ui_footer">
14          <span class="footer_text">LJMS | © Juntel Corporation</span>
15      </div>
16  
17      {% addtoblock "css" %}
18          <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}casecenter/static/css/casecenter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
19      {% endaddtoblock %}
```

The requirement.html code is:

```
{% extends "frame.html" %}

{% block base_content %}
    <div class="req_class">
        <div class="ui_head_area">
            <span class="head_title">Requirement Management</span>
            <hr>
        </div>
        {% placeholder req_placeholder_01 %}
        {% placeholder req_placeholder_02 %}
    </div>

    <div class="ui_footer">
        <span class="footer_text">iTMS | © Intel Corporation</span>
    </div>

    {% addtoblock "css" %}
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}casecenter/static/css/casecenter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    {% endaddtoblock %}

    {% addtoblock "js" %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}casecenter/static/js/requirement.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}casecenter/static/js/util.js"></script>
    {% endaddtoblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

The type of the placehoder_01 type is:  req_type_plugin 
The type of placehoder_02 is: req_plugin

The define of the placehoder_01 code :

```
class RequirementTypePlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = 'req_type_plugin'
    render_template = 'req_type_plugin.html'

    @staticmethod
    def _add_req_type(para, project):
        count = Type.objects.filter(name=para['name'], project_id=project).count()
        if count:
            status, message = 'ERROR', 'This type already exists.'
        else:
            req_type = Type.objects.create(
                name=para['name'],
                project_id=project
            )
            req_type.save()
            status, message = 'SUCCESS', ''
        return status, message
@check_login_required_flag
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        if not context['auth_flag']:
            return context

        status, message = None, None
        argpost = QueryDict.dict(context['request'].POST)
        project_name = context['request'].session['project']
        project = Project.objects.get(name=project_name)

        method = argpost.get('req_type_method', None)
        parameters = argpost.get('req_type_para', None)
        if method and parameters:
            status, message = self._operate(method, parameters, project)

        type_list = Type.objects.filter(project_id=project.id)
        context['type_list'] = type_list
        context['status'] = status
        context['message'] = message
        return context
```

The define of the placehoder_02 code :

```
class RequirementPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = RequirementInfo
    name = 'req_plugin'
    render_template = 'req_plugin.html'
    fields = ('title', 'size')

    @staticmethod
    def _add_req(para, project, context):
        count = Requirement.objects.filter(name=para['name'], project_id=project).count()
        if count:
            status, message = 'ERROR', 'This Requirement already exists.'
        else:
            req = Requirement.objects.create(
                name=para['name'],
                create_time=para['create_time'],
                owner=para['owner'],
                type_id=para.get('type_id', None),
                description=para['description'],
                project_id=project
            )
            req.save()
            status, message = 'SUCCESS', ''

        context['status'] = status
        context['message'] = message
        return context
```

The follow is apache2 error log:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
51093 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951929 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return node.render(context)
51094 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951933 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/classytags/core.py", line 153, in render
51095 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951936 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
51096 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951939 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 79, in render      _tag
51097 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951942 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)
51098 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951945 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
51099 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951948 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
51100 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951951 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
51101 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951954 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return node.render(context)
51102 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951957 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
51103 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951960 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
51104 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951963 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
51105 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951966 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
51106 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951969 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
51107 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951973 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return node.render(context)
51108 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951975 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
51109 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951979 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
51110 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951982 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
51111 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951985 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
51112 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951988 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
51113 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951991 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return node.render(context)
51114 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951994 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/classytags/core.py", line 153, in render
51115 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.951997 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
51116 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952000 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 264, in render_tag
51117 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952008 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     content = get_placeholder_content(context, request, page, name, inherit)
51118 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952011 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 182, in get_placehold      er_content
51119 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952014 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     content = render_placeholder(placeholder, context, name)
51120 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952018 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/plugin_rendering.py", line 127, in render_placeholder
51121 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952021 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     content.extend(render_plugins(plugins, context, placeholder, processors))
51122 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952024 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/plugin_rendering.py", line 81, in render_plugins
51123 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952027 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     out.append(plugin.render_plugin(context, placeholder, processors=processors))
51124 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952030 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/models/pluginmodel.py", line 173, in render_plugin
51125 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952033 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     context = plugin.render(context, instance, placeholder_slot)
51126 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952036 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/home/wuwenzhong/itms/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapped_render
51127 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952039 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return render(*args, **kwargs)
51128 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952042 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/home/wuwenzhong/itms/plugins/casecenter/cms_plugins.py", line 98, in render
51129 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952045 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     project_name = dpdk
51130 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952048 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
51131 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952052 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
51132 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952055 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
51133 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952058 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256]     self.model._meta.object_name)
51134 [Thu Sep 29 14:44:48.952061 2016] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 140112253376256] DoesNotExist: Project matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: what is case_placeholder_01 and 2?

Comment: two django_cms plaugin

Comment: Please specify what plugins you have in the placeholder.